# How can play pause audio using Xamarin

Tags: android, audio, xamarin.forms

I am using Plugin.MediaManager.Forms for play audio file in xamarin forms.

i used this code for play audio

```
 public async void PlayAudio(string UrlPath)
    {
        var mediaFile = new MediaFile
        {
            Type = MediaFileType.Audio,
            Availability = ResourceAvailability.Remote,
            Url = UrlPath,
            MetadataExtracted = true
        };
        await CrossMediaManager.Current.Play(mediaFile);
    }
```

and audio play perfectly then i paused audio via this code.

```
    private async void PauseAudio(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      await CrossMediaManager.Current.Pause();
    }
```

and i used this code for Play pause audio but not work

```
    private async void PauseAudio(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      await CrossMediaManager.Current.PlaybackController.PlayPause();
    }
```

Hello Developer where i am wrong and how can play pause audio in xamarin forms using **Plugin.MediaManager.Forms** Packge

[and i attached a file of given permission](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vFrus.png)

Comment: Hi Deepak, in your Play paused audio code it looks like you have just copied the paused audio again?

Comment: Ya @james an i edited this

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
private async void PlayPausedAudio(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await CrossMediaManager.Current.PlaybackController.Play();
}
```

To resume a paused track.

Comment: Hello @james i used await `CrossMediaManager.Current.PlaybackController.Play();` but not work

Comment: You must request AccessWifiState, Internet, MediaContentControl and WakeLock permissions in manifest. Have you granted those permissions?

Comment: ya i given these permission i edit my pauseplay method in my question please see once again.

Comment: It says in your question that ...PlaybackController.PlayPause(); but I am saying just use ...PlaybackController.Play();

Comment: Yes I used `CrossMediaManager.Current.PlaybackController.Play();` but not work
i am getting CrossMediaManager.Current.Status every time Stopped but in background audio is playing

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

**PlayMethod:**

```
 public void PlayAudio(string urlPath)
    {
        var mediaFile = new MediaFile
        {
            Type = MediaFileType.Audio,
            Availability = ResourceAvailability.Remote,
            Url = urlPath,
            MetadataExtracted = true
        };
        CrossMediaManager.Current.Play(mediaFile);
    }
```

**Play and Pause Methos:**

```
 private async void PauseAudio(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       var mediaPlayerStatus = CrossMediaManager.Current.Status;

            if (mediaPlayerStatus == MediaPlayerStatus.Playing)
            {
                 CrossMediaManager.Current.Pause();
            }
            else
            {
                 CrossMediaManager.Current.Play();
            }
    }
```

Get the media player status first and then play and pause the audio. This is what I have done in my project.

Comment: @Deepakyogi, make it synchronous methods instead of async and also check for internet permission. It should work. I have prepared the demo and it is working fine.

Comment: Hello @Jaymin i attach a permission file in my question

Comment: @Deepakyogi, Please check updated answer. This is what I have done in my project and it is working.

Comment: Hello @ Jaymin i am getting CrossMediaManager.Current.Status every time Stopped but my audio is running.

Comment: You need to debug it why it happens.

Comment: Hello @Jaymin could you give me your demo project.  i tried every thing but not work

Comment: @Deepakyogi, The file size is in GB. Not able to send over here. can you please check the URL of audio or send here?

Comment: this is audio link **http://crm.office24hr.com/content/kksong.mp3** please check and tell me

Comment: @Deepakyogi, MP3 is working. There is a specific issue in android only. The same code I have tried in iOS, which is working fine. In Android, MediaPlayer status return stopped every time.

Comment: Any solution for this issue

Comment: I am looking for it. If I will find it. I will update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

To pause

```
  void PauseClicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
  {
      CrossMediaManager.Current.PlaybackController.Pause();
  }
```

To Play

```
void PlayClicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{            
    CrossMediaManager.Current.PlaybackController.Play();
}
```

Comment: please give me documentation link